# Visual Studio 2015 reordering open documents when selected

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If I have multiple files open in VS, and I select a file by clicking on its tab, it repositions its tab order by moving the selected file to the left.
How do I disable it?

Comment: Do you have any plugins active?  I have the same issue, and trying to figure out is this default behaviour, or one of my plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I found what was causing the behaviour.  I have the Productivity Power Tools extension.  Under their "Custom Document Well", in "General", there is a Sorting option.

Turn of the "Most Recently Used" option (like in the image).

[image]